# Execute Javascript function from Rails controller (without rendering or reloading the view)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to execute a Javascript function included in application.js or the corresponding js.coffee file from a controller, but *without* rendering or reloading the view? I.e. just a simple

```
def connect()
  call js: "connect_through_javascript();"
  render :nothing => true
end
```

but instead of rendering :nothing, is there some way the view could be left untouched?
Also would it be possible to send params with it, i.e.

```
def connect(param1, param2, param3)
  call js: "connect_through_javascript(#{param1}, #{param2}, #{param3});"
  render :nothing => true
end
```

The Javascript function called will in turn go to another controller action for it's callback.

I'm about to try with the Paloma gem, but I just wanted to know if any of this is possible without adding dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is AJAX. JavaScript will then have to do something intelligent with the HTTP response body in the success callback if using a JavaScript library, like jQuery, or if the readyState is 4 and the status is 200 if using native JavaScript.

You're stuck with the HTTP request-response lifecycle.

EDIT: Here is a simple example:

**The HTML**

```
<ol id="comments"></ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", "/posts/123/comments_ajax");

    xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

**The Rails Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def comments_ajax
        @comments = Comment.where(:post_id => params[:id])
    end

end
```

**The contents of `app/views/posts/comments_ajax.html.erb`:**

```
<%= @comments.each |comment| do %>
    <li><%= comment.text %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear implementation example. :) The Paloma gem seems to work for my current problem but in some cases I'd prefer your solution.

Comment: I haven't used Paloma before. Looks interesting. I gather that it's a Ruby class lib for making Ajax easier on the Rails side, plus a JavaScript class lib to make creating JavaScript classes to interact with Rails RESTful services easier?